# Async sometimes returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise, cheerio

When calling the following method:

```
getLyrics: async function(song) {
    const body = await this.getSongBody(song);
    const lyrics = await cheerio.text(body('.lyrics'));
    return lyrics;
}
```

as such:

```
genius.getLyrics('What a wonderful')
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

Everything works fine and the lyrics of "What a wonderful world" by Louise Armstrong pops up in the console.

However, when I run the same code but without "await" in front of "cheerio.text..." sometimes the lyrics are produced and other times "undefined" shows up in the console. What has been making me scratch my head for a while now is that "cheerio.text..." does not return a promise (albeit "getSongBody" does), so to my understanding, there is no need to "wait" for it to finish.

I'm clearly missing something about async/await but have no idea what. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

EDIT: Added a reproducible example as requested below:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');


// API
function geniusApi(token) {
    this._token = token;
    this._auth = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this._token};
};

geniusApi.prototype = {  
    getSongURL : async function(search_keyword){
        const res = await fetch('https://api.genius.com/search?q=' + 
                                 search_keyword,{headers: this._auth});
        const body = await res.text();
        const body_parsed = JSON.parse(body);

        if (body_parsed.response.hits.length == 0){
            console.log('No such song found');
            throw Error('No such song found');
        } 

        const url = body_parsed.response.hits[0].result.url;
        return url;
    },

    getSongBody: async function (song){
        const url = await this.getSongURL(song);
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const body = await response.text();
        const body_parsed = cheerio.load(body);
        return body_parsed;
    },

    getLyrics: async function(song) {
        const body = await this.getSongBody(song);
        const lyrics = cheerio.text(body('.lyrics'));
        return lyrics;
    }
}

// TEST EXAMPLE
const token = 
'OTh1EYlsNdO1kELVwcevqLPtsgq3FrxfShIXg_w0EaEd8CHZrJWbWvN8Be773Cyr';
const genius = new geniusApi(token);

genius.getLyrics('What a wonderful')
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Comment: Added reproducible example, sometimes it will print the lyrics and other times it won't print anything. The token is temporarily added as I doubt anyone would bother going through the trouble of getting their own token.

Comment: What does `cheerio.load` return? A function?

Comment: @Bergi it returns a jQuery-like object for selecting on the parsed DOM

Comment: @Mageer does the return value of `body()` or `cheerio.text()` return an object with a `.then()` method?

Comment: @Bucket no, when trying to treat either as a promise I get something like "TypeError: body(...).then is not a function".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who ever stumbles upon the same issue, the problem in this case had nothing to do with async, promise or any other JS feature. It was merely a coincidence that the code had functioned correctly while using async, it later turned out that it didn't always work with async either.

**The reason was simply that the *Genius API* that I was using to fetch the data, would return different source codes for identical API queries.**

Two different source codes were returned, one contained a div called "lyrics" while the other did not. Therefore, sometimes the lyrics were found using cheerio, other times, they were not.